# libodbc++ - Memory Leak

Tags: odbc, unixodbc

`I am facing memory leak on each connection creation with database in libodbc++ library (0.2.5). I have copied valgrind log here. Used the below code to create and delete the connection. Any suggestion to fix the issue. Is libodbc++ stable to use ?

Sample Code:

```
`while(1)
{
    Connection* con = DriverManager::getConnection(ConnectionString);
    if(con != NULL)
    {
        delete con;
        con = NULL;
    }
}`
```

Valgrind Log:
`==7534== 283,173,984 (1,074,640 direct, 282,099,344 indirect) bytes in 9,595 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7,279 of 7,279 ==7534== at 0x4CE9B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so) ==7534== by 0x6FEB3B7: __gconv_open (gconv_open.c:74) ==7534== by 0x6FEB070: iconv_open (iconv_open.c:40) ==7534== by 0x3172BEB: unicode_setup (__info.c:601) ==7534== by 0x3136BD7: __SQLAllocHandle (SQLAllocHandle.c:492) ==7534== by 0x310DC4F: odbc::DriverManager::_createConnection() (drivermanager.cpp:140) ==7534== by 0x310DDBC: odbc::DriverManager::getConnection(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits\<char="">, std::allocator\<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits\<char="">, std::allocator\<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits\<char="">, std::allocator\<char> > const&) (drivermanager.cpp:183) ==7534== by 0x</char></char,></char></char,></char></char,>`

I have tried debugging libodbc++ library. SQLAllocHandle and SQLFreeHandle called properly for each connections and SQLFreeHandle returns SQL_SUCCESS. Memory not released by SQLFreeHandle. I didnt face connection leak. `

Answer (score 0):

I arrive late to this discussion, but there's indeed a memory leak in the Linux's ODBC framework regarding connection handles. I finally had to create a script that kills my application from time to time in order to release memory (fortunately it's not critical). Nobody in the Linux community seems interested in fixing this bug since it's been around for at least 15 years already.